# Jquery поиск input [type="text|email"]

Tags: jquery

Как правильно выбрать первый попавшийся input, type  у которого равен text, email или tel, а если равен redio или checkbox, то ненужно брать?

```
$(".el input[type='text|email|tel']:first").val();
```

Правильно ли?

Comment: Не работает, уже проверял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на костыль

```js
var a = $('input[type="text"]:first, input[type="email"]:first, input[type="tel"]:first').val();
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="el">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
</div>
<div class="el">
  <input type="text" value="4">
</div>
<div class="el">
  <input type="email" value="1">
</div>
<div class="el">
  <input type="tel" value="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам не додумался в простоте)